# Good with maven 3.12.0, but 3.13.0:pmd failed: MavenReportException: /workspace/my-project/.out/reports/pmd/pmd.xml (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, maven, pmd

Question about maven PMD plugin.

I used to have maven pod plugin version 3.12.0
Very happy with this plugin, it was configured that way, everything was working fine.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetDirectory>.out/reports/pmd</targetDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>target/reports/pmd</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

However, I wanted to upgrade to the newest version 3.13.0 and I am now facing this issue.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetDirectory>.out/reports/pmd</targetDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>target/reports/pmd</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.13.0:pmd (default-cli) on project my-project: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.13.0:pmd failed: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: /workspace/my-project/.out/reports/pmd/pmd.xml (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
```

This is literally a one character change. The 3.12 version is working perfectly fine, while with 3.13.0, it is failing 100% reproducible.

May I ask what is the issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed with version 3.14.0 of the same plugin by PMD team.